# Plugin with out plugin.xm or metainf.mf

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

Is it possible to have a Eclipse plugin without plugin.xml or metainf.mf file ?

Comment: At least `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` is required which contains the `Bundle-SymbolicName` (plug-in ID), the `Bundle-Version` (plug-in version) and the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It might not need a `plugin.xml`, but a plug-in absolutely needs the `MANIFEST.MF`.